# Assuming a descent at 250kt IAS and idle thrust, will the resulting ROD be higher at a higher GW, or lower?

Tags: aerodynamics, descent

I was recently told by a pilot that it works in inverse order: Keeping indicated airspeed steady, and using idle thrust, the rate of descent will be *lower* with a *higher* gross weight (and a *higher* rate with a *lower* gross weight).

Somehow this does not make sense to me.

Comment: "Will" questions are answered yes/no, but I think you also want to know *why,* so does this answer your question? [Why does an airliner have a shallow descent when heavier, opposite to gliders with ballast?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/75181/why-does-an-airliner-have-a-shallow-descent-when-heavier-opposite-to-gliders-wi)

Comment: Yes, the answers and comments to this question explain the "why", thank you